# Using a PHP function collection or how to avoid many files

Tags: php, function, collections

I wonder if it is possible to use a single PHP file which is declaring all necessary functions  instead of creating a unique file for every one.

For example, i've got a form which submits a text to phpscript.php. Another form is sending a date. I would do this like this:

```
        <form id="text" method="post" action="textscript.php">
            <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        </form>

        <form id="editForm" method="POST" action="datescript.php">

            <input name="date" type="date" /><br />
            <input id="submitDate" type="submit" /><br />

        </form>
```

Now i would like to declare functions.php, which contains both procedures and then use this file for form action. I have just no idea idea how to achieve this as well as i already tried to give an URL-Parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into the [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FrontController) to dispatch "function calls".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do this!

Simply create a file like functions.php, and in every file you want to use these functions use `include`. Check the [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) documentation on include for more information on how to use include.

Example

```
<?php

include ("functions.php");

?>
```

Comment: Thanks so far, but i already noticed this. Problem here is that i would still have to create a new file where i could include my collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a hidden input value.

```
<form id="editForm" method="POST" action="functions.php">

        <input name="date" type="date" /><br />
        <input id="submitDate" type="submit" /><br />
        <input type-'hidden' name='function' value='datescript' />

    </form>

    <form id="text" method="post" action="functions.php">
        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
        <input type-'hidden' name='function' value='textscript' />
    </form>
```

and then in your functions.php, you can catch them from `$_POST['function']` and

```
    if($_POST['function'] == 'datescript'){
      //do the relevant things
    }
    if($_POST['function'] == 'textscript'){
      //do the relevant things
    }
```

hope this helps :-)

Comment: That's an interesting solution, will try :)

Comment: Certainly what he is asking, but not either a nice or clean way to do it

Comment: Maybe it's better to check the date and text field. If date is present, you need to use the 'datescript' and if text is present you can use the 'textscript'.